# istio envoyfilter send access log into kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, istio, envoyproxy

I need an envoyfilter that send envoy access logs into kafka. i use `envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog`
to send logs into stdout but i didn't find a way that send that access log into kafka i try to find a typed_config to send that automatically

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: access-logs-to-kafka
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      app: my-app
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: ACCESS_LOG
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: envoy.access_loggers.kafka
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.kafka.v3.KafkaSink
            config:
              brokers:
                - broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092
              topic: access-logs
              message_format: "%START_TIME% %REQ(:METHOD)% %REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)% %PROTOCOL% %RESPONSE_CODE% %RESPONSE_FLAGS% %BYTES_RECEIVED% %BYTES_SENT% %DURATION% %RESP(X-REQUEST-ID)% %UPSTREAM_HOST%\n"
```

but it seems that there is no kafkasink
and i didn't anything else

do you guys have similar experiment?

Comment: Hi Amir, did you find any solution for this? We are also looking for something similar

Comment: @anony i didn't find a builtin solution , but there are two ways, one is two log this into stdout and use a logging software like fluentd to send data to kafka, and the second way that i didn't try is to use webassembly and write a code to send the logs to kafka